# ggplot2: How can I connect dots selectively

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have six dots:

```
 x_11, x_12, x_13, x_21, x_22, x_23.
```

I want to draw lines that connect `x_11 with x_12 and x_13`, but not a line between `x_12 and x_13`.

After that, I want to do the same thing to `x_21, x_22, and x_33`.

That is, I want to connect `x_21 with x_22 and x_23,` but not `x_22 and x_23`.

I tried the group method (adding the group attribute in aes) but it connects all three dots.

Is there a way to conveniently solve the problem?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Please share your code and sample input data to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The group method works fine if you do it right. If you share code and data we can tell you what you're doing wrong.